# Select2: How to get previous selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using select v4.0.3. How do I get the replaced/previous value of the select element? I already attached a 'change' listener but I can't seem to find the previous value.

Answer (score 10):

Previously selected value can be acquired by using `select2:selecting` event

see the codes here: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/ZpGvkx?editors=1111

```
$('select').on('select2:selecting', function (evt) {
  console.log('previously selected ' + $('select').val());
});
$('select').on('select2:select', function (evt) {
  console.log('now selected ' + $('select').val());
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do it in the selecting event:

```js
$(this).on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
  var curentValue = e.val;
  var previousValue = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oldname;//global declaration
$('select').on('select2:selecting', function (evt) {
  oldName= $('select').val();
});
$(select).on("select2:select select2:unselecting", function (e) {
   //For selecting the new option
   var currentName= $(this).select2('data')[0].text;
   console.log(oldName);//you can get old name here also
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

This handles the selecting of a Select2 where you can get both the old and the new value and compare them if needed

```
$('select').on('select2:selecting', function (evt) {
    var oldSelect2Value = $(this).val();

    evt.preventDefault(); //this prevents any value from being changed yet

    var newSelect2Value = evt.params.args.data.id;

    //and if you want to set the new value:
    var conditionToChangeValue = true; //you can put any condition here if you want to apply the new value or keep the old value

    if(conditionToChangeValue){
        //this sets thew new value you have selected :
        $(this).val(newSelect2Value).trigger('change').select2("close");  //it needs to be closed manually
    }
    else{
        //this here keeps the old value;; you don't need to write extra code to apply the old value since it already has that value
    }
});
```

And if you want to manually trigger only 'select2:selecting' :

```
var someSelect2Value = "1";

$('select').val(someSelect2Value).trigger('change').trigger({
    type: 'select2:selecting'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get previously selected value

```
$(document).on('select2:selecting', 'select', function (evt) {
   console.log('previously selected value :' + $(this).val());
});
```

Get current selected value

```
$(document).on('select2:select', 'select', function (evt) {
   console.log('current selected value : ' + $(this).val());
});
```

If you want to perform this function for a specific select use class like below

```
$(document).on('select2:selecting', 'select', function (evt) {
   if ($(this).hasClass("select_email_type")) {
      console.log('previously selected value :' + $(this).val());
   }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).